# How to set the added elements by jQuery to the behind of other element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a play list based on SoundCloud API. I have a list that when an `li` is pressed a new div element will be added to the content of the `li`. I use append() methond to do so, and it works but it adds the div element to to front, so the text that already existed in the element goes behing. How can I change it?
My CSS code:

```
.list > li {
    background:#eee;
    display:block;
    position: relative;
    background:;
    padding:10px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #fff;
}
.currentSong {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.8;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.currentSongLoad {
    background:black;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.6;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<li>
    <h3 class="name">Jonny Stromberg</h3>
    <p class="release">1986</p>
</li>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".list li").click(function () {
    $(this).append("<div class=\"currentSong\"><div class=\"currentSongLoad\"></div></div>");

    SC.get("/tracks/155552335", function (tracks) {
        trackWaveform = tracks.waveform_url;
        $(".name").text(tracks.title);
        $(".release").text(tracks.release_year);
        $(".currentSong").css({
            background: "url(" + trackWaveform + ") top center no-repeat red",
            "background-size": "100% 100%",
            width: "100%",
            height: "100%",
            left: "0"
        });
        console.log(trackWaveform);
    });

    SC.stream("/tracks/155552335", function (sound) {
        sound.play({
            whileplaying: function () {
                $(".currentSongLoad").css('width', ((sound.position / sound.duration) * 100) + '%');
            },
        });
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/danials/6Djwd/8/

Any idea to put the `.currentSong` at the back of the other elements (`h3` and `p`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boom Your Problem Solved: [h3-p-tags-behind-song-layer](http://jsfiddle.net/mr_eirenaios/6Djwd/12/)

css

---

```
.list {
    font-family:sans-serif;
    margin:0;
    padding:20px 0 0;
}
.list > li {
    height:50px;
    background:#eee;
    display:block;
    position: relative;
    background:;
    padding:10px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #fff;
}
.currentSong {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.8;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.currentSongLoad {
    background:black;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.6;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
h3 {
    position:absolute;
    color:#fff;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin:0 0 0.3rem;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-weight:bold;
    z-index:999999;
    height:10px;
}
p {
    position:absolute;
    color:#fff;
    margin:0;
    z-index:999999;
    margin-top:25px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it is still the same. The text is in behind. To check you change the opacity of the `.currentSong` and the text disappears.

Comment: wait now i understood what you want!